# Woocommerce: Add Cart in Single Product page does not working

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am new to WooCommerce.

Interestingly, Add Cart in single product page does not working (No response at all). However, when I am in Shop page (shows multiple products), that "add to Cart" button works.
Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this?

The website is this: http://dev.myhexa.com/shop/hexa-bluesky-lucky/

Best Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a fundamental error on your single product template.
HTML forms needs submit button not an anchor tag.

put this

```
<input type="submit" data-quantity="1" data-product_id="<?php echo $product->id; ?>" class="single_add_to_cart_button add_to_cart_button  product_type_simple button alt" value="Add to cart" />
```

Instead of this

```
<a data-quantity="1" data-product_id="1162" class="single_add_to_cart_button add_to_cart_button  product_type_simple button alt">Add to cart</a>
```

You can find those tag in your `theme-dir/woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/simple.php`

Comment: Thank you. But still not working after I replaced to this code. <input type="text" data-quantity="1" data-product_id="<?php echo esc_attr($product->id); ?>" class="single_add_to_cart_button add_to_cart_button  product_type_simple button alt" value="Add to cart"/>

Comment: Oh my bad, it's `type="submit"` not `text`. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much! :)